# URL redirection from united-domains to free webspace (bplaced.net) bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, web-hosting, redirects, free

I have the following URL at united-domains.de: ffm-nachhilfe.de.
Currently I use the Webspace from united-domains.de (I am still in the first free month) but after the first month it will cost 4 Euro per month which is not few for a poor student. Consequently I want to use free webspace instead.

I found http://www.bplaced.net/ where I can get 2GB webspace for free. I like this. Under "Address for CNAME" I found for my account at bplaced.net the following address: richard87.bplaced.net
If I understand correctly I would now need to redirect my URL ffm-nachhilfe.de on the homepage of united-domains.de to this address.
As I can see I now have three choices:

1. Header-Redirect (this would be suicide, because then everybody
   would read for example "richard87.bplaced.net/kontakt.html" as he
   actually should read "ffm-nachhilfe.de/kontakt.html". Did I
   understand that correctly?)
2. frame redirection (disadvantage: you would not see any more the
   full URL for example if you are on ffm-nachhilfe.de/kontakt.html the
   browser would just always tell you "ffm-nachhilfe.de")
3. URL-hiding. As I understand correctly you would see then the full
   URL (like this!) but it could be a little bit lame sometimes.

If I understand correctly the third way is the only human way to keep (full) face. My questions now are:

1. Did I understand that correctly?
2. If I would choose URL-hiding would that hurt my SEO?
3. Should I just rather pay the 50 Euros per year and don't be so stingy?

I hope my questions weren't too silly and I appologize for my German accent (and by accent I mean style mistakes). Thank you very much in advance for your great help!

Comment: "4 Euro per day" - I think you mean "per month"? What is "3) URL-hiding"? "2GB webspace for free" - hmmm, what's the _catch_?

Comment: Thank you, w3d, for the correction! Of course I meant 4 Euro per month! :D I corrected that.

Answer (score 1):

> ... my account at bplaced.net the following address: richard87.bplaced.net If I understand correctly I would now need to redirect my URL ffm-nachhilfe.de on the homepage of united-domains.de to this address.

On ffm-nachhilfe.de you need to redirect users to richard87.bplaced.net and header redirect is best.

If you use apache and have mod_rewrite installed, you can add these lines to .htaccess and save it to the document root folder at ffm-nachhilfe.de:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ffm-nachhilfe\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://richard87.bplaced.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then visit redbot.org and test a page from ffm-nachhilfe.de and you should see at least the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://richard87.bplaced.net/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike for your answer. One question to make it clear: If I follow your rules will this cause that if a user visits my HP he will actually see "ffm-nachhilfe.de/kontakt.html" instead of "richard87.bplaced.net/kontakt.html" if I do those rewriting things? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use the rewrite rules, things should work in your favor. The best thing to do is to try everything out after making changes.